# How to count the total number of events in a splunk search result?

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

```
index=apigee headers.flow_name=getOrderDetails  
| rename content.orderId as "Order ID"
| table  "Order ID" 
| dedup "Order ID"
```

I wish to count how many unique order IDs are received in the result.

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Define your question accordingly https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 1):

```
index=apigee headers.flow_name=getOrderDetails  
| rename content.orderId as "Order ID"
| table  "Order ID" 
| stats dc("Order ID")
```

`stats dc()` will give you a distinct count for a field, that is, the number of distinct/unique values in that field.